# cannot show list items in html for using for loop

Tags: html, django, loops

I cannot show list items in HTML for using for loop.
But there is no problem when try shows separately x and i.

### models.py

```
def dp1():
    result=list(engine.execute("select a,b,c,d  from my_Table where a='201811' and rownum<4"))
    return result
```

### Views.py

```
def dp (request):
    con()
    result=dp1()
    y=range(0,len(result[0]))
    return render(request, 'pages/detail.html', {'result': result,'y':y})
```

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table BORDER='1'>
        {% for x in  result %}
             <tr > 
                {% for i in y%}
                    <th >  {{x.i}} </th>
                {% endfor %} 
             </tr> 
        {% endfor %}     
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you can not use a range object (y) with the for tag

Comment: please show me your result object data. and what do you want to print in html